# Where can I find the latest version of version of Jquery Cycle Lite minified?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I've searched and it's not on their [site](http://jquery.malsup.com). I need the Latest Version: 1.3.1 (07-OCT-2011).  Haven't so far found it on Google.

I know I could use a javascript minifier but sometimes it messes things up.

**Thanks a lot**,
Cris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it here:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/download.html

Here is the direct link:

http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.lite.js

Minified link:

http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.lite.min.js

Comment: The lite one is smaller because it has less functionality/options. That's the one I have but I need the minified/compressed version of it.